# A finite set has no limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am looking for an easy to remember proof to the statement "A finite set has no limit points". The best proof I found say that

> Any finite set is composed of isolated points only. Since for any
>   isolated point there exists a neighborhood that does not contain any
>   other element of the set, a finite set cannot have any limit points.

Is this proof correct and is there a way to represent this mathematically?

Comment: *Stop* tagging these questions with [set-theory].

Comment: This depends on your definition of limit point. In the text I used a limit point did not need to have a sequence of distinct points converging to it.

Comment: The intersection of a finite number of neighborhoods of $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. So you can avoid all other elements of the finite set (assuming the topology is Hausdorff).

Comment: Are you speaking of general topological spaces or of the real line in particular?

Comment: In R^n define m to be the minimum among all pairwise distances between points; the existence of m relies on your finiteness assumption. Then an open ball of radius m around any point p in your set contains only p, which shows p is not a limit point. So there are no limit points in the set.

Comment: @AnotherPerson Does the term "limit point" have more than one definition? Rudin defines it as a point $p$ such that every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point from $E$ ($\subset X$ where $X$ is a metric space.) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) says the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not convinced.

Definition: s is a limit point of S if every open set that contains s contains a second distinct element of S.

Consider a finite  non-empty set X of two or more elements with the indiscrete topology. Every point is a limit point. (there are only two open sets in the indiscrete topology, {}, and X itself).

Comment: Are all the points of a finite set are isolated points?

Comment: @Jake No. they aren't. Definition:  a point x∈A is said to be an isolated point of A if there exist an open set containing x which does not contain any point of A different from x. So in my example finite set there are no isolated points.

Comment: @Jake. It would be correct to conclude from the definitions that a point is an isolated point if and only if it is not a limit point.

Comment: Given the context, one suspects that the sets in question are subsets of the reals (with the usual topology).

Answer (score 2):

The point $a$ is a limit point of the set $A$ if every open neighborhood of $a$ (i.e. every open set of which $a$ is a member) contains some member of $A$ other than $A$.

**No matter how small** you make an open neighborhood of $a$ it still contains some member of $A$ other than $a$.  That means $a$ can be approached from within $A$.

In order to prove the desired result, you must be working in a space in which, for every point $b$ other than $a$, there is some open neighborhood of $A$ that excludes $b$.  That happens in metric spaces and in many other topological spaces.

Let's say your finite set is $\{a=a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n\}$.

Then some open neighborhood of $a$ excludes $a_2$;
and some open neighborhood of $a$ excludes $a_3$;
and some open neighborhood of $a$ excludes $a_4$;
and so on $\cdots$
and some open neighborhood of $a$ excludes $a_n$.

The intersection of those open neighborhoods of $a$ is an open neighborhood of $a$ because the intersection of finitely many open sets is open.  There you have an open neighborhood of $a$ that excludes all other members of $A$, so $a$ is not a limit point of $A$.