# Prove that if there exists a subsequence of $a_{n}$ which converges to $L$ , then $L$ is a limit point of $a_{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Let $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers, and let $L$ be a real number. Then the following statements are logically equivalent:

(a) $L$ is a limit point of $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

(b) There exists a subsequence of $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which converges to $L$.

**MY ATTEMPT (EDIT)**

I am mainly concerned with the implication $(b)\Rightarrow(a)$.

Let us start with the definition of convergent subsequence.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists a natural number $N\geq 0$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
f(n) \geq n \geq N \Rightarrow |a_{f(n)} - L| \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}

where $f:\textbf{N}\to\textbf{N}$ is strictly increasing.

The definition of limit point which I was presented to is the following:

For every $\varepsilon > 0$ and every natural $N\geq 0$, there exists a natural $n\geq N$ such that $|a_{n} - L| \leq \varepsilon$.

But then I get stuck. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Yes, now recall what you need for $L$ to ba limit point. For any $\epsilon>0$, open ball around $L$ of radius $\epsilon$ contains one point of sequence. Doesn't it follow from the $|a_{f(N)}-L|<\epsilon$? By the way the statement is equivalent with strictly less than sign.

Comment: What's your definition of a limit point? Is it that every open ball around the limit point contains an element of the sequence not equal to the limit point? If so, you just have to notice that $\vert a_{f(n)}-L\vert<\varepsilon$ just says that the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $L$ contains $a_{f(n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to prove that $L$ is a limit point of the *set* $\{a_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which is actually the range of the function (called a sequence) that maps the natural number $n$ to the real number $a_{n}$. The definition of $L$ being a limit point of this set is that, for every $r>0$, there exists a real number $a_{n(r)}\in\{a_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\setminus\{L\}$ such that
\begin{equation} |L-a_{n(r)}|<r. \end{equation}
First of all, you need to assume (or it is probably written in the question) that $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is not eventually constant because then its range would be finite and finite sets have no limit points (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589779/a-finite-set-has-no-limit-points#:%7E:text=Any%20finite%20set%20is%20composed,cannot%20have%20any%20limit%20points.)). Assuming that $\{a_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is an infinite set, then consider the following argument.

Let $r>0$ be given and suppose that $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ has an *infinite* subsequence convergent to $L$. Choose $N$ such that $|L-a_{n_{k}}|<r$ for all $k\geq N$. If $a_{n_{N}}\neq L$, then you are done. If $a_{n_{N}}=L$, then choose the first $N'\geq N$ such that $a_{n_{N'}}\neq a_{n_{N}}$ (there is such an element because the subsequence is infinite). Then, $|L-a_{n_{N'}}|<r$ and $a_{n_{N'}}\neq a_{n_{N}}=L$ so you are done.